# Why would a SQL Server SELECT statement work within a SET statement, but fail on its own?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SQL below works fine in the following context:

```
USE ThisDB

UPDATE guest.TABLE2
SET this_var = (SELECT count(T1.key_field)
                FROM ThisDB..TABLE1 T1
                WHERE T1.key_field = guest.TABLE2.keyfield
                   AND T1.date_field between (DATEADD(DAY, -7, guest.TABLE2.other_date)) and guest.TABLE2.other_date)
```

However, on its own, the `SELECT` statement (below) fails with error

> The multi-part identifier 'guest.TABLE2.keyfield' could not be bound. (4104)

```
SELECT 
    count(T1.key_field)
FROM 
    ThisDB..TABLE1 T1
WHERE 
    T1.key_field = guest.TABLE2.keyfield
    AND T1.date_field BETWEEN (DATEADD(DAY, -7, guest.TABLE2.other_date))  
                          AND guest.TABLE2.other_date
```

Comment: Because you are not joining the guest.Table2 in your select statement.

Comment: This is called *correlation*. The inner query is correlated to the outer query.

Comment: You have selected as a correct answer an answer that does not answer your original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    (
    SELECT count(T1.key_field)
    FROM ThisDB..TABLE1 T1
    WHERE   T1.key_field = guest.TABLE2.keyfield
        AND T1.date_field between
            DATEADD(DAY, -7, guest.TABLE2.other_date) and guest.TABLE2.other_date
    ) as newValue
FROM guest.TABLE2;
```

One simple way to convert your `update` to a `select`. Essentially I converted the `set` to `select` and move the table name into a `from` clause.

You could also look into using `range` with `count() over ()` if you have a later version of SQL Server. It appears that you're fairly new to SQL so that would be an advanced concept.

The reason that the subquery will not run on its own is as I mentioned above in a comment. The inner query refers to a column of the outer query, which is called *correlation*. When you pull that out and attempt to run it separately there is no longer any way to resolve that reference.

Answer (score 2):

guest.TABLE2.keyfield belongs to the updated table which does not exists in this query

---

This is  a query with the same logic as the update.
For each record of T2 you are going to get the value for update based on T1.

```
select      guest.TABLE2.*
           ,(SELECT count(T1.key_field)
                FROM ThisDB..TABLE1 T1
                WHERE T1.key_field = guest.TABLE2.keyfield
                   AND T1.date_field between (DATEADD(DAY, -7, guest.TABLE2.other_date)) and guest.TABLE2.other_date)

from        guest.TABLE2
```

Comment: OK, thank you. So would this be resolved by adding guest.TABLE2 to the FROM statement or would that produce a different result from the original? (with UPDATE)